# How can I supress Keychain authentication prompt programatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, authentication, keychain

I am working on an app which accesses the keychain access app. I dont want the keychain authentication prompt asking the user to enter the password. Is there any way to supress the prompt programatically?

Comment: From a security POV it is necessary for the user to authenticate to the system.

Comment: True, but is there any such possibility of doing it programatically?